# Proving using ideal gas law that molar volume at NTP is 22.4 litres

Tags: gas-laws

The definition of NTP as given by IUPAC is

> NTP – Normal Temperature and Pressure – is defined as air
> at $20\ ^\circ\mathrm C$ ($\pu{293.15 K}$, $\pu{68^{\circ}F}$) and $\pu{1 atm}$ ($\pu{101.325 kN/m2}$, $101.325\ \mathrm{kPa}$, $14.7\ \mathrm{psia}$, $0\ \mathrm{psig}$, $29.92\ \mathrm{inHg}$, $407\ \mathrm{in}\ce{H2O}$, $760\ \mathrm{Torr}$).
>
> It is also known that volume occupied by $1$ mole of gas at NTP is
> $\pu{22.4 L}$.

My attempt at proving the above statement,

For $1$ mole,  $PV=RT$

Substituting $P=\pu{1 atm}$, $T=\pu{293 K}$,  $R=0.0821\ \mathrm{L\ atm\ K^{-1}\ mol^{-1}}$, we get $V=\pu{24.05 L}$ as the molar volume.

On putting $T=\pu{273 K}$ and $P=\pu{1 bar}$ (conditions of STP), we get $V=\pu{22.2 L}$

Therefore, molar volume at STP is $\pu{22.4L}$.

Why is the above calculation in NTP condition giving wrong results? How else to prove that molar volume at NTP is ${22.4\ \mathrm L}$?

Comment: see the whole article and the linked section in particular https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_conditions_for_temperature_and_pressure#Molar_volume_of_a_gas

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that one mole of a gas at NTP should not be 22.4 L based on the ideal gas. This is only true for a gas at STP. The key difference between the two conditions is they are defined by different temperatures (STP is for 273 K while NTP is for 293 K).

They are also different in that the IUPAC now defines STP with respect to 1 bar while NTP is defined with respect to 1 atm.

See [The Engineering ToolBox](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/stp-standard-ntp-normal-air-d_772.html) for more info.

Comment: And to add further point, the pressure is one bar, not one atm. So at STP it would be more correctly $\pu{22.7L}$.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal good point, I will make note of that explicitly.

Comment: You should use 298K for NTP!

Comment: @Vaibhav Dixit all the definitions I have seen for NTP define it at 20C or 293K.